# Gamma distribution what is scale and rate

Tags: terminology, gamma-distribution

I have question regarding the gamma distribution when using

```
alpha <- 3
beta <- 3
x <- rgamma(n = 100, shape = alpha, scale = 1/beta)

fitdistr(x,"gamma"
```

I get shape to 3.9 and rate to  3.4.

**Are the rate=beta or is the rate=theta? What is the difference between scale and rate?**
Note: I did not understood what they said on Wiki

Comment: These are defined in the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the notations on wiki, there $\theta$ is the scale parameter.
So, $1/\theta$ is the rate. That means $1/\theta$ corresponds to $\beta$.

Comment: How can I then get the Beta estimate out of the rate estimate?

Comment: In your output you have rate. That means rate = $\beta$

Answer (score 1):

It may be worthwhile having an extended discussion on what a scale parameter is, what a rate parameter is with respect to an exponential random variable, and how the exponential relates to the Gamma.

The TL;DR is this:

> The gamma can be viewed as the sum of iid $n$ exponential random variables.  Exponential random variables have a rate parameter, so it makes sense for the Gamma to inherit a rate parameterization.  The rate parameter also happens to be related to a scale parameter, so it makes sense for the Gamma to have a scale parameterization.

Let's break this down a little more.

### What *is* a Scale Parameter?

[According to wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter), a scale parameter is a parameter $s$ for which the density of a random variable satisfies

$$ f_s(x) = f(x/s)/s$$

Let's take a look at the Gamma distribution,

$$ f(x) = \dfrac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma (\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x}$$

and try to identify the scale parameter.  After some thinking, you might say that the scale parameter is $1/\beta$.  Do verify this, we need to show that the first equation in my answer is satisfied.  Let's start by setting our proposed scale parameter to 1 (so $\beta=1$) and then manipulate $f(x/s)/s$ to see what we get.

$$ f(x/s)/s = \dfrac{1}{s} \times \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\left(\dfrac{x}{s}\right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/s} $$

Now, we proposed $s=1/\beta$.  After some algebra, you find that this expression is equivalent to

$$ = \beta \times \dfrac{\beta^{\alpha -1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} $$

Which is $f_s(x)$.  So we've proved that $1/\beta$ satisfies the requirements for being a scale parameter.

### What *is* a Rate Parameter for an Exponential Random Variable?

The exponential distribution is often used in modelling failure times for various things.  If the failure time $T \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\beta)$ then we should expect $\beta$ failures per unit time.  This makes sense too when you think about the expected value for an exponential random variable (if I get $\beta$ failures per unit time, then on average I should expect to wait $1/ \beta$ units of time per failure).

### How are The Gamma and Exponential Related

Now, I'm not a historian of statistics, but I anticipate that the shape and rate parameterizations for the Gamma could be viewed as coming from the following relationship:

> The sum of $n$ iid exponential random variables with rate parameter $\beta$ has gamma distribution with shape parameter $n$ and rate parameter $\beta$.

Various proofs of this are found on this site and on Wikipedia, but you can easily simulate this in R or something to verify it empirically

```r
n <- 12
beta <- 1.2

rvs <- replicate(1000, {

  sum(rexp(n, beta))
})

hist(rvs, freq = F)
curve(dgamma(x, shape = n, rate = beta),, col='red', add=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

##### The "scale" and "rate" are essentially multipliers/divisors of a unit-scale gamma

The notation we use for the parameters of the distribution is somewhat arbitrary, though there are common conventions.  Conventionally, we use $\theta$ to denote the *scale parameter* of the gamma distribution and we use $\beta$ to denote the *rate parameter* of the gamma distribution.  These are related by $\beta = 1/\theta$.

A useful way to remember the meaning of the parameters is that the "scale" is essentially just a multiplier of the random variable and the "rate" is the corresponding divisor.  If $X \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, 1)$ then we have:

$$\begin{align}
\theta X &\sim \text{Gamma}(\text{Shape} = \alpha, \text{Scale} = \theta), \\[6pt]
\frac{X}{\beta} &\sim \text{Gamma}(\text{Shape} = \alpha, \text{Rate} = \beta). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

From these results we can see that one way to think of a gamma random variable as a scaled version of an underlying unit-scale gamma random variable.